# jwquery - keep buffering to show percentage of buffering while do not play a video,(1st only clicked on video)

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have an setup of default settings on jw-player script, in this case i need to show progress bar of percentage of buffering a full video, if buffer is completed then play the video.

My problem is finding the buffer percentage differ on chrome and fire fox,

please guide me.

Comment: Do you have an example of where you are running this?

Comment: Why are you buffering the full video? If the MP4 file is configured correctly (with -movflag fastart), it will stream, and the site visitor doesn't have to wait for the whole thing to buffer.

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer, i have an example on local file. i don't have live script.

Comment: @MisterNeutron, i need this type of buffering of full video, can u give me some example for this???

Comment: If the video is encoded correctly, the player will buffer only the first few seconds of it, then start playing it. It will continue to download the video, staying as far ahead of the playing portion as it can. (This is how YouTube works.) It doesn't have to wait for the whole video to download before it starts playing. To encode your own videos properly, use Handbrake with default options, plus check "Web optimized." http://handbrake.fr/. Or use an application like MP4 FastStart to put the moovatom where it belongs. http://www.datagoround.com/lab/

Comment: And without seeing where you are running this, are just guessing.

Comment: @MisterNeutron, thanks i would with buffering of full video was done with how many percent it will buffered. using event handlers of onBuffer and OnBufferchange.. thanks so much for your reply, how can i show loader on displayview???

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer, im not guess, it need for my site, thank you so much ethan, i have done

Comment: events: {onBuffer: function(evt){if(jwplayer('container').getBuffer() == '100'){jwplayer("container").play();} ....},onBufferChange: function(event) {...},onPause: function(event){if(jwplayer('container').getBuffer() == '100' || wplayer('container').getBuffer() > '97'){if(event.newstate == 'PLAYING'){$('#progressbar').hide();}}else{...}},onPlay : function(event){if(jwplayer('container').getBuffer() == '100' || jwplayer('container').getBuffer() > '97'){...}else{jwplayer("container").pause();}}onComplete: function() { jwplayer("container").play();}}

Comment: @Ethan Jwplayer above is my code.. working fine in firefox and chrome

Comment: We need a link to an actual, live, viewable site. Posting some mangled code in here is not good enough. And I still can't imagine why you would want to do what you're asking. With a properly encoded video, the buffering should last for only a few seconds, after which time your site visitor will be watching the video, and couldn't care less about any further buffering.

Comment: Exactly, please provide a link.

Comment: sorry lol, im working on IIS not moved to live, if so i will give url